# Annoying `Pending` status in GitLab's CICD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using GitLab SaaS and I have a private CI runner on AWS EC2 with a lot of resources. The server is very fast and properly setup but GitLab keeps showing the `Pending` status for a few minutes before the job starts running. When I restart the runner it runs the job immediately but I can't keep doing this.

My questions is, how does the runner work? is it long pulling jobs, is there any configuration that can help minimize this wait time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check your `config.toml`, config.toml file in:

- `/etc/gitlab-runner/` on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is executed as root (this is also the path for service configuration)
- `~/.gitlab-runner/` on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is executed as non-root
- `./` on other systems

and check your `concurrent` and `check_interval` value.

- `concurrent` - Limits how many jobs can run concurrently, across all registered runners
- `check_interval` - Defines the interval length, in seconds, between new jobs check. The default value is 3. If set to 0 or lower, the default value is used.

reference:

- [Advanced configuration | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html)